# How can I retrieve brands based on specific category in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I can retrieve all product based on specific **category_name** and **Brand** name, but i can not retrieve **brands** name based on specific **category_name**. How can I do this?

**My Category Model**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='Category')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique="True", help_text="Slug is a field in autocomplete mode, but if you want you can modify its contents")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

**My Brand Model**

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name
```

**My Product Model**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, help_text='Add Product Model Name or Product Name.')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="", blank=True, related_name="Products")
    brand_name = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="", blank=True, related_name="Products")
    specification = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, default="")
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False, default=0.00, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)], help_text='Price Can not be Less than Zero.')
    quantity = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['category', 'brand_name', 'product_name', 'specification'] ]
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

Comment: Try Brand.objects.filter(product__category__category_name='your_cat_name')

Answer (score 1):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Brand.objects.filter(Products__category=my_category).distinct()
```

or for a category name:

```
Brand.objects.filter(
    Products__category__category_name=my_category_name
).distinct()
```

the [**`.distinct()`** call <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)
prevents returning the same `Brand` multiple times.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*.
> Since the value for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> specifies the name of a field that will be defined on the target model, the value of the `related_name=…` parameter should be written in *snake_case* as well, so it should be: `products` instead of <s>`Products`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Your `Product` model acts as a junction table for a many-to-many relation between `Category` and `Brand`. You can span a
> [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)
> on the `Category` model with:
>
> ```
> class Category(models.Model):
>     # …
>     brands = models.ManyToManyField(
>         Brand,
>         through='Product'
>     )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your models it should be something like:

```
brand_names = Product.objects.filter(category__category_name="some_name").values_list("brand_name__brand_name", flat=True)
```

or if by brand_name you mean Brand model instances then

```
brand_names = Product.objects.filter(category__category_name="some_name").brand_name.all()
```

(BTW I would consider renaming fields in your models. In Product model rename `brand_name` to just `brand` and inside Brand rename field `brand_name` to just `name`. The same for Category. It will be much less confusing)

Comment: i also tried that no duplicate brand_name will show up. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `.distinct()` to get rid of duplicates. In the case of the `values_list` you can convert `list` to `set`